systemd - service that starts on server boot
We have a development VM that occasionally reboots. I would like to have a systemd service running there that starts automatically on boot, before any user session. I have tried making a user service with WantedBy=default.target, but it only starts on login, not on boot. The service needs some private keys to start and run, so I am reluctant to turn it into a system service. Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

How is turning it into a system service impacted by the fact that it needs private keys? Have it run as the appropriate user so the permissions on the keys stay exactly the same as they are right now.
